# How do I use a global variable in unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller

I need an object that was initialized in the first test in other tests too.
To prevent code duplication, I want to save the object I created in the first test in a global variable. This is what I did:

```
namespace Project.WebUIV2.Tests {
    [TestClass]
    public class FilmSelectieControllerTests {
        private FilmSelectieController controller;
        [TestMethod]
        public void CanInitializeController() {
            Mock<IRepository<Voorstelling>> mockIRepository1 = new Mock<IRepository<Voorstelling>>();
            Mock<IRepository<Film>> mockIRepository2 = new Mock<IRepository<Film>>();
            Mock<IRepository<Zaal>> mockIRepository3 = new Mock<IRepository<Zaal>>();
            Film film = new Film { titel = "Film" };
            mockIRepository2.Setup(m => m.Add(film));
            var repository1 = mockIRepository1.Object;
            var repository2 = mockIRepository2.Object;
            var repository3 = mockIRepository3.Object;
            var controller = new FilmSelectieController(repository1, repository2, repository3);
            Assert.IsNotNull(controller);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(controller, typeof(FilmSelectieController));
            this.controller = controller;

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void IsCreated() {
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(controller, typeof(FilmSelectieController));
        }
    }
}
```

Testmethod CanInitializeController() succeeded, while isCreated() failed.

In the first test i created the FilmSelectieController object.

How do I use that object in next tests?

Thanks to Anthony Pegram

**Solution:**

```
..*/
private Controller controller;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize() {
    var parameter = /*...test data that i need in all tests...*/
    this.controller = new Controller(parameter)
}

[TestMethod]
public void test1 {
    result = controller.FirstMethod();
    //assert something
}

[TestMethod]
public void test2 {
    result = controller.SecondMethod();
    //assert something
}
/*..
```

Comment: you should recreate it every time in a setup routine.

Comment: That's what i did at first, then i thought that that would be code duplication and I thought there would be a way to prevent that.

Comment: write a new method. duplication is fine to me in unit tests.

Comment: if you see yourself duplicating a lot of code, try abstracting it into a class/method that clearly expresses the intent. Duplication is not good in unit tests per se, if your code changes, you don't want to update 600 unit tests with just about the same snippet. Invest in your test projects design and architecture, it's essentially part of your production code, if not more important.

Comment: `Assert.IsInstanceOfType(controller, typeof(FileSelectieController))` is completely worthless after calling `controller = new FileSelectieController`. The .NET framework guarantees that `controller` will be that type unless the constructor throws an exception, which would the test to fail before it even gets to the assert.

Comment: Haha I came across your question, we're working on the exact same project! (Also at the Avans Hogeschool)

Comment: Cool, are you at explore la4 too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a method to run on initialization and setup any object that needs to be available for all tests within that method. (The method will rerun before each test, so do not expect state to persist.)

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
     // your common setup code here
     this.controller = ...
}
```

(`TestInitialize` is the attribute under MS Test, a similar attribute will be available under most other testing frameworks you might use.)

I typically do this for stubs and mocks that I will be using in the test. As far as setting up the class I'm actually testing, I'll typically handle that in the test method itself or refactor it out to a private helper method, but that's just a personal preference. If the setup of the class under test is also uniform for all your tests, then it can also go in the initialization method.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

You are mixing several things so let me point out a few things wrong with this approach.

### Isolation

A good unit-test is a test that is -amongst several other aspects like speed, repetitiveness, etc- isolated. This means that the outcome or the order of other tests should not have an influence on the outcome of another test. Every aspect of a good-unit tests is equally important because without them you might as well not use unit-testing in the first place.

### Setup

If your tests rely on a certain snippet of code to work properly then you can initialize this in the appropriate scope (assembly or class initialization).  You use the `[Initalize]` or `[AssemblyInitialize]` annotations for this (most of the time you want class initialization).

Important note: these are *not* tests!

### Test code, not tests

Take another look at the code shown above. Let me sum up what you do:

- Create mocks
- Create `Film` object
- Setup repository to return film
- Create controller with mocks injected
- Asserted the controller is created
- Asserted the controller is of a certain type
- Setting the instance level variable

This is wrong for 3 reasons:

- You setup one mock to return data but never test it.
- You create a controller and then test whether it is created and that it is of the right instance: as pointless as pointless actions can be.
- You assign the instance level variable which won't have any effect on the other tests (and shouldn't either: see the principles of a good unit-test).

---

Nowhere in your code are you testing your actual problem domain, you're just setting up stuff for tests. Also note that some clearer names for your mocks wouldn't hurt. There is also no guarantee for the order in which unit-tests in a single class are run.

Comment: Thanks for these tips :) this is my first unit testing ever and these tips are really usefull.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use a the decorator [TestInitialize]
This is used for iniatilizing the test sequences before  all [TestMethods] are executed